# Multiple groups - how to regularise estimate of level 1 parameters based on level 2

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, methodology

I am fitting some relatively complex structural equation models, but the specific model is not so important. I am estimating multigroup models, such that one parameter is completely free across groups, and others are constrained to equality. This results in a too high variance of the free parameter, as the variance is a sum of true and estimation error variance. What I would like to do is to regularise the estimation of the free parameter, so that the variance (over the estimates of this parameter for each group) better reflects the generating (normal distribution) model.

I have found a number of approaches to this problem (James-Stein, random effects, etc) but have not been able to find anything appropriate for this situation. I can easily arbitrarily regularise the variance (by including an additional model over the estimated parameters, penalising my likelihood function according to, for example, squared variance of the free parameters). However, I would like something like the James-Stein estimator, but in the form of a penalty to the maximum likelihood, based on the level 2 variance estimate (the variance of the free parameter across groups) and, I guess, the amount of information used to generate the free parameter estimates.